# How to get Mix UI to show buttons at top of scenario module

Tags: mix

Was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SeJcWZQMfoI&nohtml5=False) and saw at about 8:11 a bunch of UI buttons at the top of the Mix scenario module (right 1/3 of screen) that I don't have in mine. I verified I have the latest, 1.0.2. I am playing with Mix on a laptop. How do I get access to the features shown, e.g., add account?

The only button I have is the dark yellow one in scren shot below - the two curvy arrow refresh button. The other buttons to its right (airplane, one I can't describe, and the person with + sign) aren't there. I suspect this might be because of the smaller laptop screen.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this coulee be posted as an issue or support ticket on the original software.

Comment: @NikhilM I could rephrase a bit but was wanting to know if there's a way to get the UI to show up.

Comment: That will again makes it off topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions [instead of combining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) your questions into one. [That way](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @NikhilM I disagree, I see some potential here if it's well written.

Comment: @NikhilM - edited, let me know whatcha think

Comment: @5chdn - edited, let me know what you think. thanks!

Comment: reopened, I totally understand your question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just looking for the buttons because I remember it was a bit tricky to find them, and I was a bit puzzled *not* to find them at all.

It seems they were (re)moved to a context menu. To find the features, click the button **Show Right View**:

[image: right view]

Then you will find the features in the context menu of the big '**+**':

[image: buttons]

The usability of mix shows a lot room for improvement ;-)

Comment: I have those two options under a menu icon that is three horizontal lines instead of a plus sign, in the same place. Maybe my version is slightly newer than yours. But that still doesn't explain where the third missing option is, unless they removed that third feature. (There were four icons in total shown in UI in the video.) I might just wait for a newer video with accurate UI, since your answer mostly resolves that I'm not having a small-screen problem. Thanks.

Comment: The fourth is "Add Account", not sure where this feature is hidden now, can't find it anymore.